# Android Open PDF Intent

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, xamarin

I need to open a PDF. I know the procedure, this is my code:

```
string file_path = _path + url.Substring (5);
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(file_path)) {
                    Android.Net.Uri pdfFile = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile (new Java.IO.File (file_path));
                    Intent pdfIntent = new Intent (Intent.ActionView);
                    pdfIntent.SetDataAndType (pdfFile, "application/pdf");
                    pdfIntent.SetFlags (ActivityFlags.NoHistory);
                    _parent.StartActivity (pdfIntent);

                    return true;
                }
```

I'm using Xamarin, and the path exists because i check it as you can see.
The app opens Adobe reader, but when it starts an error message shows up saying (File not found). So, my file is in

`/data/data/com.myapp/files/.hide/contents/file_test.pdf`

Are there some permission to set? I really don't understand why it can't open my file!

Answer (score 0):

The folder `/data/data/com.myapp` is the private folder of your application. So no other application can access to the content of this folder (in this case Adobe reader).

Instead try to put your pdf into a SDCard folder.